# What value is k equal to, the system of homogeneous linear equations has only trivial solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

kx + y - z = 0
x + ky - z = 0
2x - y + z = 0

Can't understand the difference between finding k in the systems with trivial and nontrivial solutions. I've solved the same lin.equation, but in the conditions was written " If th following system of homogeneous linier equation has nontrivial zeros, what value k is equal to?" and k was = 4, -1. But in this question answer is -2 and 1

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The system has only the trivial solution iff the coefficient matrix is non-singular. This is so iff the determinant of this matrix is not $0$.  The correct answer is $k \neq 1, k \neq -2$.

Comment: How did you find 1 and -2?

Comment: @56656565 By actually computing the determinant.